# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapps, out-of-gas

I am running into out of gas exception while calling this function : `contractInstance.createProposal("ADHD", "Foo", 2, {from: web3.eth.accounts[1]})` . I'm super new to ethereum and I would really appreciate some help!

Here's my super simple contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract DataProvider {

struct Proposal {
    address owner;
    uint id;
    bytes16 name;
    bytes32 desc;
    uint pool_size;
    address[] consents;
    bool initialized;
}

address public admin;
Proposal[] public proposals;

function DataProvider() {
    admin = msg.sender;
}

function createProposal(bytes16 nm, bytes32 ds, uint n) {
    address[] memory cons;
    proposals.push(Proposal({ owner: msg.sender, id: proposals.length, name: nm, desc: ds, consents: cons, pool_size: n, initialized: true }));
}


}
```

Comment: with a gas limit of 3000000 your code works properly

Comment: @itachi first welcome to the community, since you seem to be new to the community, FYI, It's better and would be useful when answering an question if you can mention what you tried to solve the problem and what were the outputs of those when asking a question. Good luck :)  .

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake Gotcha, will do next time for sure :) Thanks for being so kind about it!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First check your account balance :  `balance = web3.eth.getBalance(someAddress);`
then try to specify the gaslimit `contractInstance.createProposal("ADHD", "Foo", 2, {from: web3.eth.accounts[1], gas:3000000})`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! :) Also, I had a couple other functions too which I haven't included for simplicity but then they all worked fine. Why does this function consume so much more gas than others?

Comment: it depends on the computation and the used storage

Comment: @BadrBellaj I changed the gas limit to 3000000 using [remix](https://photos.app.goo.gl/NBAexqdpBz26on738). But its still giving me `out of gas` error. Did i have to change gas price as well? My current gas price is 20000000000.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Badr Bellaj worked for me but I had to specify 
`contractInstance.method.myMethod`  instead of just `contractInstance.myMethod`.
This made me looking for a solution for days although I tried this immidiatly after the error occured.